# Difference between the_post_thumbnail and get_the_post_thumbnail in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been working on developing a wordpress theme and I noticed a lot of the Wordpress functions have two versions to them the normal one such as the_post_thumbnail and than the same one with get_ in front of it.

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<?php get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

This isn't just for the_post_thumbnail, since I see this on a lot of different wordpress functions and was wondering what the difference is between the two since they appear to do the exact same thing and want to make sure I'm using them correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

WordPress functions starting with `get_` generally [return](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php) data, while their non-prefixed counterparts [echo](http://www.php.net/echo) (i.e. print) data.

Answer (score 6):

`the_post_thumbnail()` works only in post code and return featured image of current post. `get_the_post_thumbnail()` works everywhere and get $post_id parameter at first attribute.

Like this ~:

```
the_post_thumbnail($params) = get_the_post_thumbnail($current_post_id,$params);
```

This is realization in WP engine:

```
function the_post_thumbnail ($size='post-thumbnail', $attr=''){
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( null, $size, $attr );
}

function get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id = null ) {
    $post_id = ( null === $post_id ) ? get_the_ID() : $post_id;
    return get_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', true );
}
```

if `$post_id is NULL` - used `get_the_ID()` of current post.

Comment: Ok thanks, so I I want to call a post thumbnail on a post other than the post that I"m on I would use the get version correct? Where if I"m within the loop just use the one without get.

Comment: Correct. Get version with ID of post you're need.

Answer (score 1):

`the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr )`

1. It is used when you are in the post loop.
2. It prints the output directly. You can't assign it to a variable.
3. It has 2 parameters as specified above.

`get_the_post_thumbnail( $post, $size, $attr )`

1. It can be used outside the loop as well. You can pass post id or post object in the first parameter.
2. It returns the data. The output can be assigned to a variable.
3. It has 3 parameters as specified above.

For other functions, most of the properties are applicable in each case of `get_`

The more detailed answer is provided in this post [How to get featured image in WordPress](https://webolute.com/blog/wordpress/wordpress-get-featured-image-the-post-thumbnail)